# DateTime internal representation to FILETIME

Tags: c++, c, datetime, sql-server

Here is a routine I put together to convert SQL Server's internal `DateTime` representation (`BINARY(8)`) to a `FILETIME`. I know that the SQL `DateTime` (as in `GetDate()`) is not precise and will vary from the `SystemTimeAsFileTime`. But it should be different by milliseconds, but by seconds, right?

In any case, here is my routine and I was wondering if anyone saw any flaws in it:

```
int SQLDateTimeToFileTime(PULARGE_INTEGER t_sql, PULARGE_INTEGER t_ft)
{
    ULONGLONG days = t_sql->LowPart;
    ULONGLONG ticks = t_sql->HighPart;
    days += (ULONGLONG) 109207;         // 01/01/1900 - 01/01/1601
    days *= (ULONGLONG) 864000000000;   // (FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY * FT_SECOND);
    ticks *= (ULONGLONG) 33333333333;   // MS per tick (3.33...) * 10000);
    ticks /= (ULONGLONG) 1000000;       // to avoid floating point operation
    days += ticks;
    t_ft->QuadPart = days;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Comment: If you're using ADO, you could just do [VariantTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

- This function always returns `0`, but you haven't stated why that's important for this use (if it's intended).  Since it doesn't also return `1` or another non-0 value for failure, I assume that it's not returning error codes.  Otherwise, it should return `void`, and the `return 0` should then be removed.
- Since this is also tagged with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I'll also provide the C++ equivalent of the constants given in @chux's answer:

  ```
  constexpr unsigned long long FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24ULL * 60 * 60;
  constexpr unsigned long long FT_SECOND = 10000000ULL;
  ```

  ([`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) has them evaluated at compile time.)

  Or for brevity, they can use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) instead:

  ```
  constexpr auto FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24ULL * 60 * 60;
  constexpr auto FT_SECOND = 10000000ULL;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

1. Rather than the coder performing multiplication, let the compiler do it

   ```
   // days *= (ULONGLONG) 864000000000;   // (FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY * FT_SECOND);
   #define FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY (24ULL*60*60)
   #define FT_SECOND 10000000ULL
   days *= FT_SECONDS_PER_DAY * FT_SECOND;
   ```
2. What is `FT_SECOND`?  The name maybe should be FT_ten_millionths_per_second or better documented.  Per the original line of code and its comment, it appears to have the value of 10,000,000.  Why?  It seems arbitrary. The reason for this value needs to be made more clear.
3. The comment says `(3.33...) * 10000` but the code uses a rounded value with `*= 33,333.333333`.  Better to do `*= 33,333.333333333333333333....` with simple math.  Explaining why a scaling of 10,000 would be useful.  Likely `FT_SECOND/1000`.

   ```
   // MS per tick (3.33...) * 10000 = 10/3*10000 
   ticks *= (ULONGLONG) 10*10000;
   ticks /= 3;
   ```
4. Though not yet employed, consider using the return value of non-0 for an error indication should some field or parameter be out of range.